# Javascript libraries conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, semantic-ui, jquery-ui-contextmenu

I have a web page that uses this JS libraries:

- calendar_en.js --- (www.dhtmlgoodies.com, v2.1.2)
- jquery-min.js --- (jQuery v3.2.1)
- jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js
- jquery-ui.min.js --- (jQuery UI - v1.12.1)
- jquery.ui-contextmenu.min.js --- (jQuery UI context menu plugin - v1.18.1 - 2017-08-28 |  https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu)
- semantic.min.js --- (Semantic UI - 2.2.13)

I attach a context menu to some elements, like this:

```
$("#objPanel").contextmenu({
  menu : [ .... ]
  beforeOpen : function(event, ui) etc...
});
```

The application was running perfectly until I added Semantic UI JS script. Fron then, the context menus don't appear anymore. The console doesn't show any warning or error, so I don't know what's preventing the code to work. How could I troubleshoot the problem?

Cheers,

Comment: I just found out that the context menu stops working as soon as I call the Semantic UI JS function: 

`$('.top.sidebar').sidebar();`

I'll try to call also the context menu code when I have to open the sidebar and I'll post the results.

Comment: I tried to run the context menu creation code after the sidebar is hidden, like:

   ` $('.top.sidebar')
      .sidebar({
      onHide: function() {
        console.log('on hidden');
        loadContextMenus();
      }
  });`

But the result is the same... I have no clue on how to solve this....

Comment: I think it's because both jQuery and semantic try to use `$` to denote that their functions should be called. You can google how to get jQuery to use a different character for that.

Comment: I used the 'noConflict' jQuery function but it does the same. I think that Semantic 'sidebar' function does something to the DOM that disables the context menu. I'm watching the DIV that is bound to the context menu to see if there are any changes when I open the sidebar but so far I can't see any difference. Sooo frustrating...